# How to properly set the background of a keyboardview in android

Tags: android, keyboard

(1) I have implemented a keyboard and i am trying to give it a look alike current default keyboard. I have set the background color of the keyboard as:

android:keyBackground="@color/background_color"

but this gives me a white color but not the exact color that i want.[image]

(2) And also how can i change the font style of these keys??

## keyboardview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyBackground="@color/background_color"
    android:keyTextColor="#757575"
    android:keyTextSize="26sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif" 
    android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Latin IME reference for customizing your keyboard.

This will help you to customize your keyboard.

Comment: how to do that?? or any link!!

Comment: but i couldn't find the section that describes font customization of the whole keyboard keys. @Basant Kumar